# Action item always appears in the overflow menu

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I am using v7 Support library and using app namespace in the menu_main.xml file. Even then, the action is never displayed in the action bar but in the overflow bar. This happens even when I use `app:showAsAction="always"`

menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_box_black_icon"
        />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the items is important - swap the create order and settings if you want to achieve your original idea.

Comment: @KaushikS Do you inflate your menu anywhere, or use only the `context` specified here?

Comment: I inflate it in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: @KaushikS yup, you should - maybe add this method also, just to verify it. Also, I usually do not add the `context` attribute and have never faced such an issue. Maybe try without..